# Can I create new account to use while my primary account is suspended?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, ethics

My account was suspended for voting irregularities. I had created two accounts and voted my main account. This resulted in suspension. I understand it is unfair and I would not repeat it again after the suspension period gets over.

My question however is can I create another account? I would not be indulging in voting fraud again and would try building reputation from start. However the created account is from the same computer or laptop suggesting it is from the same IP address.

**Is it right to have two accounts one does not interfere with the other?**

Comment: Why exactly do you want this?

Comment: I want to start answering again. Right now i cannot do the same with my suspended account

Comment: No you should not do that. Wait 5 days, the world won't end and you'll still have plenty of questions to answer when you get back.

Comment: So you're asking whether it's right to create a new account to circumvent a suspension on the old one? No, it isn't.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if the world ends before 5 days are up, then I'm blaming it on you.

Comment: Why you have so hurry to answer ? Enjoy 5 day's vacation.

Comment: -1 from me as well as I just understood you created that other account anyway.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the account is deleted and i don't want to long suspension again.Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: @Raghunandan Remember this, Each offense increases the suspension period. Most offenders give up after a while or get suspended for a very, very long time.

Comment: @Raghunandan glad the lesson is learned, hope you can put this behind you and come back with fresh power to Stack Overflow within 30 days.

Comment: This question would have held some water with me if it had come *before* the new account was created and started posting content.

Comment: @AndrewBarber i din't know creating a new account was wrong. i had doubt's over the same. So i asked one here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suspension is set for a reason, you should not try and bypass it no matter what might be the reason.

Wait a few days, the world won't end and you'll still have [plenty of questions to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) when you get back.

Also keep in mind that you have [100 other sites in the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users), might be a good time to expand your horizons. :)

Comment: but i am not indulging in any voting fraud with the new account created. I know it is not good to have 2 accounts. But is it allowed? Would the account be deleted by moderators?

Comment: @Raghunandan how can we be... Delicate about this? ***NO***.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII so you are suggesting the account will be deleted or it is not good to have 2 accounts?

Comment: @Raghunandan the issue here is not the two accounts, it's you trying to bypass the suspension. That is simply not acceptable. Normally it's totally legit to have two accounts (I [have another shadow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/206610/shadow-of-the-shadow)) as they don't interact with each other.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd the suspension is not for the new account created right? If i am fair in gaining reputation should not be a problem right?

Comment: @Raghunandan your new account will soon be merged with your suspended account. DO NOT CREATE NEW ACCOUNTS. Please. It's for your own sake, otherwise you'll just get suspended for longer time (month or even a year).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd then pls delete  or merge my  the same to my main account http://stackoverflow.com/users/2312484/raghunandan

Comment: @Raghunandan I can only flag (which I did), but I'm pretty sure that it will be done soon.